# Kohana PHP and module hooks

Tags: php, hook, kohana

We're running a fairly customised version of Kohana PHP, where we have a extensive amount of base modules running and used for each web page.

I've been tasked in speeding up some of our applications and one of the modules we use and have written, which is included into every application, has a hook which initializes sessions.

Now this isn't a problem for the majority of apps, except for the one we have that serves images, as it's just being called by other apps, so sessions aren't needed.

So for instance we have the module hook: `/modules/mod_name/hooks/sessions_hooks.php`

In my app, I have the app hooks directory: `/application/hooks/sessions_hooks.php`

From the looks of things, the application hooks is not overriding the module one. I tried creating a similar module structure under my app to the main kohana module directory, but that didn't help either. It actually looks like modules are fully loaded before anything else happens, but I could be wrong.

How do I go about overriding a module hook with a website application hook?

Answer (score 0):

You cant. Kohana includes every hook file. What if you add special checks in that module hook? For example, you can load config value.

Comment: I was under the impression that Kohana was a cascading file system and files that are in application take precedence over the modules directory. From the Kohana docs: `application > modules > system`

Comment: Wrap your hook entry into Helper/Library (and call it via hook). This way you can quickly disable this via Cascading FS

Comment: I'm not sure I follow @biakaveron